# Find string which starts from function

Tags: scripting, installshield

I have question about InstallShield script, is there a function to find a string that startsWith("example"); or no? I am asking because not sure if I should implement it by my own or it's already build. Also question if I should write it by hand how should it looks like I am not familiar with installshield script, but I am sure it does not look like in C# or Java. Any ideas guys how can I return a string that startswith?

Answer (score 0):

Use StrFindEx() for each string and set the last parameter to 0.
https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/Subsystems/installshield22langref/helplibrary/StrFindEx.htm

Comment: You need to check for a result of exactly 0 as well; otherwise it just tells you that `szFindMe` was (or was not) located somewhere within `szString`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist as such. You can use [StrFind](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/Subsystems/LangRef/LangRef.htm#helplibrary/LangrefStrFind.htm), [StrFindEx](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/Subsystems/LangRef/LangRef.htm#helplibrary/StrFindEx.htm), or [StrSub](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/Subsystems/LangRef/LangRef.htm#helplibrary/LangrefStrSub.htm) (see [String Functions](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefString_functions.htm) for the full list) as building blocks along with [operators](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefOperators.htm) like `%` and `=`.